# How to test activity kill -> recreate lifecycle with saveInstanceState

Tags: android, testing

I try to write an instrumentation test that tests the activity lifecycle where my activity gets killed and it's instance state gets saved and then gets recreated with this instance state.

I can test this behavior manually by limiting the background process limit to "no background processes" in the developer settings of my device, but I want to be able to have an automated test that proves that my activity can be recreated.

My activity has a fragment with id R.id.content_frame.

So for I have this:

```
public class MainActivityInstrumentationTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

      public void testKillCreateLifeCycleWithProfileFragment() throws Throwable {

        final Activity activity = getActivity();

        navigateToProfile(activity);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                activity.recreate();
            }
        });
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        assertProfileFragmentIsVisible((FragmentActivity) activity);
    }

    private void assertProfileFragmentIsVisible(FragmentActivity activity) {
        FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment currentFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
        assertEquals(ProfileFragment.class.getName(), currentFragment.getClass().getName());
    }

}
```

activity.recreate goes through all the live cycle callback methods and ultimalty calls onCreate with the saved bundle but the fragmentManager in my `assertProfileFragmentIsVisible` method does not contain any fragments.

Also I'm not sure whether to use activity.recreate is a right way to go. I tried many other ways like calling each life cycle method manually with `getInstrumentation().callActivityOn...`but then ultimately found no way of creating the activity with the saved bundle..

Any ideas on how I can create such an instrumentation test would be appreciated!

Regards
Frank

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anybody is interested in my final solution:

The problem was that I put the reference to the old activity to `assertProfileFragmentIsVisible`. But activity.recreate() creates a new activity instance.
The problem remains how to get this reference.

I managed to obtain a reference to the new activity by using the `ActivityMonitor`.

So my complete test now looks as follows:

```
public void testKillCreateLifeCycle() throws Throwable {
    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor mainActivityMonitor = new Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor(MainActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
    getInstrumentation().addMonitor(mainActivityMonitor);

    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    mainActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(5000);

    navigateToFragment(activity);

    runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            activity.recreate();
        }
    });
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

    Activity newActivity = mainActivityMonitor.getLastActivity();
    assertFragmentIsVisible((FragmentActivity) newActivity, getExpectedFragment());
}
```